# Android API 23 (Android 6.0) Toolbar implementation caused back button not working

Tags: toolbar, back-button-control, android-6.0-marshmallow

I found there is issue with Android API 23 Toolbar implementation. Once I implemented Toolbar in my project, my device back button is not working (Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread phone). I tried switch back to Android API 21, it is working fine. Anyone has any idea how to fix Android API 23 Toolbar problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The latest version  of support library (23.0.1) fixes this issue.

> Fixed an issue where hardware buttons did not work when an activity
>   had set the Toolbar class to act as the ActionBar by using the
>   setSupportActionBar() method. ([Issue 183334](http://b.android.com/183186))

I have the exact same problem, but I cannot post a comment so commenting as an answer.
Some code for reference:

```
public class ActivitySettings extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.e("test","onBackPressed");
}
```

If I just remove these 2 lines, the onBackPressed gets called

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

This problem occurs only in android 2.3.x. Anything above that works fine.